# Why Is My DateDiff Returning 0?

Tags: vba, excel, datediff

Column A is StartDate

Column B is EndDate

When I run the Macro it returns the answer 1 for all my dates as I am adding 1 to my DateDiff, then DateDiff must be 0.

What is wrong with my `DateDiff` ?

```
Sub CalculateDays()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim StartDate As Date
    Dim EndDate As Date
    Dim Days As Single

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'Determine last Row in Column A
         LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
         'Calculate Difference between Start Date And End Date in Days
         For i = 2 To LastRow
             StartDate = .Cells(i, 1)
             EndDate = .Cells(i, 2)
             Days = DateDiff("d", StartDate, EndDate)
             .Cells(i, 3) = Days + 1
             Days = 0
         Next i
     End With

 End Sub
```

Sample data:

```
Start Date |    End Date  
=========================
13-Feb-17  |    28-Feb-17 
14-Feb-17  |    28-Feb-17 
02-Mar-17  |    04-Mar-17 
13-Feb-17  |    15-Feb-17 
13-Feb-17  |    13-Feb-17 
15-Jan-17  |    15-Feb-17 
01-Feb-17  |    12-Feb-17
```

Comment: can you post some start and end dates that you're using?  A representative sample would go a long way in identifying your issue.

Comment: Start Date  | End Date  |
13-Feb-17  | 28-Feb-17 |
14-Feb-17  | 28-Feb-17| 
02-Mar-17  | 04-Mar-17|
13-Feb-17  | 15-Feb-17|
13-Feb-17 13-Feb-17
15-Jan-17 15-Feb-17
01-Feb-17 12-Feb-17

Comment: what format are the cells they reside in?

Comment: Why is a function/procedure even needed for this?

Comment: They are formatted as date.

Comment: then use excel, to say end-start+1 or DATEDIF ws function

Comment: why do you have `Dim Days As Single` ?

Comment: I am a novice at VBA so am trying to understand how DateDiff works.

Comment: Changed Days to long and I still have the problem!

Comment: @RyanL : I was thinking the same thing, and I'm stunned but I don't find `DATEDIF` function in my Excel 2013... I don't get why though...

Comment: @Anthony : What is `Debug.Print StartDate - EndDate`?

Comment: Will Have to figure out how to use Debug.Print

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/DATEDIF-function-25dba1a4-2812-480b-84dd-8b32a451b35c  Date diff, should be about in "Applies To:  Excel 2016, Excel 2013, Excel 2010, Excel 2007, Excel 2016 for Ma"

Answer (score 2):

Your code actually runs fine for me - but I am *sure* that the values in columns A and B are actually dates. If you are *not sure* about this then use the `CDate` function to ensure that the value in the cells is converted to a date before passing to the `DateDiff` function e.g.

`StartDate = CDate(.Cells(i, 1).Value)`

Your code with this added in:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CalculateDays()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim StartDate As Date
    Dim EndDate As Date
    Dim Days As Single
    Dim i As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'Determine last Row in Column A
         LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
         'Calculate Difference between Start Date And End Date in Days
         For i = 2 To LastRow
             StartDate = CDate(.Cells(i, 1).Value)
             EndDate = CDate(.Cells(i, 2).Value)
             Days = DateDiff("d", StartDate, EndDate)
             .Cells(i, 3) = Days + 1
             Days = 0
         Next i
     End With

 End Sub
```

### Edit

I just read [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/242b2057-d3e2-4a1a-8684-63efe62b2585/excel-2013-ignores-regional-settings-for-date-format?forum=excel) where it states a problem with South African date formats:

> .. my region was "English (South Africa)") and I had the date separator as "/", however Excel kept changing this to a "-". ...

So maybe it's worth checking on your regional settings and maybe reformat your dates as `dd/mmm/yyyy` instead of `dd-mmm-yyyy` and checking the output.

Maybe the `CDATE` function will not be required after all (as I mentioned your code ran fine for me in an Australian English regional setting context).

Comment: Also using the cdate approach you may wish to check for errors and handle that, as text of 31/02/2017 would fail cdate.

Comment: Hi Robin Mackenzie. Thanks for your advice. I tried running your code with the same results. I am using Excel For Mac 2011.

Comment: Just so you know, I tried `CDate("13-Feb-17")` and it gives a Type Mismatch error!

Comment: @R3uK - no problem when I run that in the immediate window (Excel 2013). What happens if you do `CDate("13-Fev-17")` i.e. for Février?

Comment: @Anthony - what region are you in? Obviously makes a difference with this question if you are running Excel in a non-English locale.

Comment: @RobinMackenzie : God damn it! Indeed **horrific** Regional Settings impact `CDate` too... `"13-Fev-17"` was error but `"13-Fév-17"` passed easily... I hate these Regional Settings!

Comment: @R3uK - yup - total pain. Everything would be easier if there was only Esperanto right ;) ?

Comment: @RobinMackenzie : Jes, tute!^^

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, instead of a function just write a formula:

```
=ROUND(B2-A2+1,0)
```

Answer (score -1):

why do you need datediff function. to get the days difference use

days=enddays - startdate

your code is working fine in excel 2016 in widows. As mentioned by @RobinMackenzie you have some problem with regional date settings.

Comment: I am novice at VBA and I decided to figure out how DateDiff works but it is not working for me!